# Help Understanding Correlations In Many Particle (Beam) Physics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electrons, many-body

I am having a lot of trouble looking at the statistical properties and having some sort of intuitive sense of correlations among different properties of many body systems (in particular charged ion beams).

I am wondering what mathematical tools and shortcuts we can use when two properties are correlated or uncorrelated; just a better overall understanding. Now, I understand that the way I posed this question is very vague so I'll give an example from a paper I was reading:

[image]

The above example confuses me. Is there a mathematical way of showing this?

Answer (score 2):

The rationale is this:

Assuming that $x$ and $x'$ are [random vriables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable)

Their [variances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) are given as $\left<\Delta x^2 \right>$ and $\left< \Delta x'^2 \right>$

Now the [covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) of both $x$ and $x'$ is different if $x$ and $x'$ are **correlated as random variables or not**.

If they are **not correlated** the covariance (joint correlation) is just the product of their variances:

$$\left<\Delta x \Delta x' \right>^2=\left<\Delta x^2 \right> \times \left<\Delta x'^2 \right>$$

So if the variables are un-correlated this means any correlation happens on the other dimensions (e.g $y$ and $y'$).

If the variables are correlated their covariance **is not the product of each variance**